# how to derive standard error for ROC and how to compare 2 ROC area under curve meta-analytic estimates in R using metamisc (Bayesian random effects)

Tags: r, bayesian, meta-analysis, roc

I am trying to do a meta-analysis to pool many `ROC` curves together and get an estimate of cumulative `AUC` using 2 different techniques as logistic regression(`LR`) and artificial intelligence (`AI`).

I have `95% confidence interval (95%CI)` for only some of the included studies. I found a formula to calculate the standard error for AUC`SE(AUC)` [here](https://r.search.yahoo.com/_ylt=AwrEnP52KNxkGFcS4SBXNyoA;_ylu=Y29sbwNiZjEEcG9zAzIEdnRpZANDQVEyNTUyM0NPXzEEc2VjA3Ny/RV=2/RE=1692178679/RO=10/RU=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ncss.com%2Fwp-content%2Fthemes%2Fncss%2Fpdf%2FProcedures%2FPASS%2FConfidence_Intervals_for_the_Area_Under_an_ROC_Curve.pdf/RK=2/RS=45S3H9emNfQU4ajeff7z2I7bD6A-)

[image]

- I want to be sure this is the right approach
- I want to obtain the P-value for subgroup difference between a summary ROC estimate for `AUC` for `LR` and then for `AI` i.e. compare estimates between both groups.

Here is the data sample and my code so far:

```
df<-read.table(text="study  subgroup    Model   studlab TOTAL CASES No-PPI  PPI area under the curve    AUC AUC.lci AUC.uci TP  TN  FP  FN
Study A     AI  Study A (AI)    557 462 95  81.00%  0.81            NA  NA  NA  NA
Study A     LR  Study A (LR)    557 462 95  69.30%  0.693           NA  NA  NA  NA
Study B Validation  AI  Study B (ValidationAI)  888 272 234 69.60%  0.696           0.397   NA  0.089   NA
Study B Validation  LR  Study B (ValidationLR)  888 272 234 70.50%  0.705           0.576   NA  0.274   NA
Study B Derivation  AI  Study B (DerivationAI)  272 888 704 70.30%  0.703           0.368   NA  0.111   NA
Study B Derivation  LR  Study B (DerivationLR)  272 888 704 72.60%  0.726           0.605   NA  0.372   NA
Study C 30 days: 964    AI  Study C (30 days: 964 AI)   964 775 189 0.66 (95%CI: 0.61-0.70), p <0.001   0.66    0.61    0.7 NA  NA  NA  NA
Study C 30 days: 964    LR  Study C (30 days: 964 LR)   964 775 189 0.55 (95%CI: 0.49-0.60), p <0.001   0.55    0.49    0.6 NA  NA  NA  NA
Study C 1 year: 657 AI  Study C (1 year: 657AI) 657 481 176 0.72 (95%CI: 0.67-0.76) p <0.001    0.72    0.67    0.76    NA  NA  NA  NA
Study C 1 year: 657 LR  Study C (1 year: 657LR) 657 481 176 0.54 (95%CI: 0.49-0.60) p <0.001    0.54    0.49    0.6 NA  NA  NA  NA
", sep="\t", header=T)




#############################################################################################################################
library(metamisc); ### Main
library(rjags);library(runjags);library(ggmcmc)
library(ggplot2)

### Estimate SE (AUC) for each study ROC
df$Q1<-df$AUC/(2-df$AUC);df$Q1
df$Q2<-2*df$AUC^2/(1+df$AUC);df$Q2
df$SE_AUC <-sqrt(   ((df$AUC*(1-df$AUC)+  (df$PPI-1)*(df$Q1-df$AUC^2)+  (df$No.PPI-1)*(df$Q2-df$AUC^2))
                     /
                       (df$PPI*df$No.PPI))
);df$SE_AUC

###################################################################################################################
##============= Bayesian random effects meta-analysis of the c-statistic ========================================##
###################################################################################################################

est1 <- valmeta(cstat=AUC,cstat.se=SE_AUC,cstat.cilb=AUC.lci, cstat.ciub=AUC.uci,
                cstat.cilv=0.95,data=subset(df, df$Model=="LR" ),  method="BAYES", slab=studlab);
plot(est1, col.diamond = "blue",col.predint =  "lightblue", title="A.  Included LR models")+  theme(plot.title=element_text( hjust=0.5,  face='bold'))

#=======================================================================

est2 <- valmeta(cstat=AUC,cstat.se=SE_AUC,cstat.cilb=AUC.lci, cstat.ciub=AUC.uci,
                cstat.cilv=0.95,    data=subset(df, df$Model=="AI" ), 
                method="BAYES", slab=studlab);
plot(est2, col.diamond = "blue",col.predint =  "lightblue", title="B.  Included AI models")+  theme(plot.title=element_text( hjust=0.5,  face='bold'))
```

[image]

then

[image]

Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please don't cross-post questions, https://stackoverflow.com/q/76910095/333599 see https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/147320

Comment: @Calimo Thanks for your comment. Anyway or advice to manage that? Should I delete StackOverflow post? Upvoted.